# Unable to sign-in with Apple ID on Mac - other devices work fine

Tags: macos, icloud, apple-id

I have a strange problem with logging on to my Apple ID on my Mac.  I have the correct password because I can log on to appleid.apple.com without a problem.  My iPhone is not impacted.  But I can't log on to my Apple account on my Mac.  I just get a spinning wheel in the Apple ID field and it then prompts me for my Apple ID again.

This problem started happening when my company's MDM prompted me for a password change.  I did the password change and things seemed fine.  A few minutes later I was prompted for my Apple ID.

Things attempted so far:

- Uninstalled the MDM
- Removed all traces of the MDM including profiles
- Signed out of Apple ID
- Cleared out KeyChain folders
- Updated to the latest version of macOS Monterey
- Upgraded to macOS Ventura
- Re-installed macOS Ventura over the existing installation
- Turned off FileVault

I spent 2 hours on the phone with Apple support.  I was able to create a test user account that **could** sign in to Apple.  They told me to either migrate my user settings on my Mac to a new account or re-install macOS Ventura.  I tried the re-install with no dice.

The only thing I can think of is to reformat, re-install macOS, restore my data, re-install the applications, and hope for the best.  Or to migrate my user data to a new account.

Does anyone have any other ideas?  Or tips or tools on how to migrate user data to a new account?

Comment: 1st thing to do is contact your company's MDM administrator and explain the situation. Depending on the MDM configuration, users are able to remove some MDM profiles, but there may be others which are not removable at all. In some cases, reinstalling the OS will reinstall some of the MDM profiles from your company without any way of stopping it from happening. For sysadmins like me, this is a boon for the management of many devices. For users who are stuck behind a configuration they have no control over, it can be a pain.

Comment: What @IconDaemon said.  To say it succinctly, you may be able to remove the MDM profile locally, but that doesn’t mean it’s un-enrolled from the servers.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I am the MDM admin and have verified that the MacBook is no longer enrolled in Workspace ONE (our MDM).